# Como usar o beatifulsoup para procurar determinada palavra na página

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Produto/Dunk-High-SP/153-169-211-279300"

req = requests.get(url)

html = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tamanho = soup.main.find('script', attrs={'Tamanho' : 'keywords'})

print(tamanho)
```

**Eu gostaria de procurar no elemento html da página essas palavras tamanho que é onde posso encontrar o estoque disponível para cada tênis!**

Mas em diversas tentativas o print só sai NONE.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Gostaria de fazer algo mais avançado como procurar essa palavra, tamanho ou estoque eu printar

TAMANHO 41 : 2

TAMANHO 42 : 5

e por ai vai...

Comment: Precisa ser feito mesmo com Beautiful Soup? Faça um teste comigo, vá para sua [página de exemplo](https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Produto/Dunk-High-SP/153-169-211-279300) e depois abra o console do seu navegador e digite `window.open("about:blank", "", "_blank").document.write(JSON.stringify(SKUsCorTamanho));` olhe para janela que abriu e então me responda: são esses os dados que deseja extrair?

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar os dados do objeto javascript dentro da TAG script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


html_text = requests.get('https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Produto/Dunk-High-SP/153-169-211-279300').content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

json_text = soup.find(id='produto').script.contents[0].split(' = ', 1)[1]

for tenis in json.loads(json_text).values():
    print(f'TAMANHO: {tenis["Tamanho"]} : {tenis["TemEstoque"]}')
```

Uma dica é usar a lib lxml que é mais rápida e suporta xpath